# Merge stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SupplierTableType](
    [Supplier_ID] [nvarchar](10)  NULL,
    [Supplier_Name] [nvarchar](50)  NULL,
    [Address1] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [Address2] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [Address3] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
)
GO
--------------------Procedure----------------------
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Update_SupplierTable]
      @TblSupplierTable SupplierTableType READONLY
AS
BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON;
      MERGE INTO SupplierTable c1
      USING @TblSupplierTable c2
      ON c1.Supplier_ID=@TblSupplierTable.Supplier_ID
      WHEN MATCHED THEN
      UPDATE SET 
       c1.[Supplier_Name]= c2.[Supplier_Name]
      , c1.[Address1]=c2.[Address1]
      , c1.[Address2]=c2.[Address2]
      , c1.[Address3]=c2.[Address3]
      
      WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
      INSERT VALUES( @TblSupplierTable.[Supplier_Name],
       c2.[Address1],
       c2.[Address2],
       c2.[Address3]
);
END
```

> Msg 2715, Level 16, State 3, Procedure Update_SupplierTable, Line 3 [Batch Start Line 56]
> Column, parameter, or variable #1: Cannot find data type SupplierTableType.
> Parameter or variable '@TblSupplierTable' has an invalid data type.
> Msg 1087, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Update_SupplierTable, Line 8 [Batch Start Line 56]
> Must declare the table variable "@TblSupplierTable".

Comment: BTW, without HINTS, MERGE is NOT atomic....

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a table, you have to create a data type for `SupplierTableType`.

I.e. instead of

```
CREATE TABLE SupplierTableType...
```

you have to use

```
CREATE TYPE SupplierTableType AS TABLE ...
```

See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-type-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for further info.